# сортировка лишних строк python

Tags: python, файлы, фильтрация

__Здравствуйте, есть файл с логами вида:
там присутствуют и логи из чата и логи самой игры например
в каждой строке логов из чата, присутствует:[CHAT] нужно отсортировать всё кроме строк чата. Пожалуйста помогите сижу пытаюсь 2-3 часа. Файл вида:
`[18:25:19] [Render thread/WARN]: not chat                                                                     [18:25:20] [Render thread/INFO]: [CHAT] smertelny: hello world`

Comment: есть свой код ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться регулярными выражениями, например:

```
with open(r'Путь_до_файла\logs.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not re.search('\[CHAT\]',line):
            print (line.strip())
```

Соответственно, читая файл построчно, вы можете с помощью `re.search` и необходимого вам паттерна искать наличие необходимых "фраз" и игнорировать/искать такие строки. В моём приме игнорируются все строки, где нет [CHAT].